# Visual Studio C# form's design view

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

[image: enter sddescription here]

Hi,
Where can i open form1.cs's design view? I've never had this problem before, and i searched everywhere. It hidden. I have 2 forms, i can open the second (name is AddNew) design view, but the primary form's design view is hidden.. Shift+7 not working. In the souliton bar only have the second form: AddNew.cs, and with right click the 'Open Design View' is appear. But the Form1??? I can't found, please help.
Many Thanks!
Mark

Comment: Probably because you have that public Str class in front of it.  Try to keep Form classes all by themselves in the file.

Comment: Or.. just move Str class after Form1 class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to move your `public class Str` class to be after your `public partial class Form1: Form`. Then:

Navigate to your `Solution Explorer` , find the `Form.cs` you're looking for, right click on the form, click `View Designer`.

---

The reason it is important to have your `public partial class Form1: Form` first is because that lets Visual Studios know that that file is for a `Form` rather than just another `.cs` file. Thus, letting you view the file in designer view.

It may also be helpful to add a new `Code File` to the project, and have your other classes within it, creating references as needed (for organization). This can help with `Form.cs` files as it avoids this kind of mix up from happening !

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem! That is why automaticly disappear the designer option.

Comment: Not a problem! Happy Coding!